# Authorize.Net Recurring Billing Events

Tags: webhooks, authorize.net, recurring-billing, authorize.net-webhooks

I have successfully deployed Authorize.net API(currently sandbox mode) for subscription purposes. I have also configured its webhooks that are also working. But I have a confusion that still exists even after a week on working with the said API. 
The question is, when a subscription starts in case of recurring billing(in my scenario subscription is monthly) the event that is called is

> net.authorize.customer.subscription.created

When a month passes on a subscription and next bill payment is made by the API, what event will get called? How can I capture Or to what event should I be listening to? . Is it going to be

> net.authorize.customer.subscription.updated

Currently I have clicked yes on all the all the events that are there for the webhooks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The event will be a payment related event, not a subscription related event.  Subscription related events only happen when you do something *to* a subscription (i.e. create, modify, or delete) not *with* it (make payment).

So you would look out for any of the following:

- net.authorize.payment.capture.created
- net.authorize.payment.fraud.approved
- net.authorize.payment.fraud.declined
- net.authorize.payment.fraud.held

Comment: When the `net.authorize.customer.subscription.created` event is called at first, does it also call any of the payment events for the first payment? I created a subscription starting from today, but the first payment webhook is not called. Is the webhook system even reliable? Or should we use a cronjob+api calls to check the payment status of all subscriptions?

Comment: Any answer on this? Authorize.net docs are absolute garbage compared to stripe.